# Is it possible to place several animated objects into Three.js scene?

Tags: javascript, three.js, particle-engine

I'm quite new to WebGL, and I'm trying to create cake with animated candles. So, I have found this examples: https://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Particle-Engine.html with candle flame and tried to change code due to my task (cake). But I struggled with creating several flames into same scene (I found some information how to create cubes or spheres, but unfortunately it is unhelpful in this case).
As far as I understand animated flame displaying is in the code:

```
this.engine = new ParticleEngine();
engine.setValues( Examples.fountain );
engine.initialize();
```

but I can't figure out how to create 5 different examples same time.

UPD: I finally created several instances, here is my code:

```
var engines = [];
var coordinates = [
    {x:5, y:105},
    {x:-40, y:115},
    {x:-75,y:111},
    {x:37, y:117},
    {x:68, y:110}
];
coordinates.forEach(function(item, i){
   var params = clone(Examples.candle);
   params.positionBase = new THREE.Vector3(item.x, item.y, 10);
   var engine = new ParticleEngine();
   engine.setValues(instances[i]);
   engine.initialize();

   engines.push(engine);
 }
```

**But** when I tried to set different example (smoke from examples) to one instance all other instance's parameters had been changed too. Can't figure out how to change each instance separately without any influence others.

Comment: Just make an array of `ParticleEngines` and call `new ParticleEngine()` 5 times? This doesn't sound like a problem related to WebGL

Comment: @UnholySheep, thanks. I tried to do this, but unfortunately result was unexpected - instead of 5 candle flames in proper coordinates there were one super-bright(sorry if I define it vaguely). Maybe I better should make 5 transparent scenes one above another?

Comment: You can create 5 instances of `ParticleEngine` and use their `positionBase` property to set the position you want for each instance, for example: `engine.positionBase.set(0, 10, 0);`

Comment: @prisoner849, thank you a lot! That was the problem, I tried to 5 instances, but one objects with params(not 5 different objects, forgot that objects copying "by reference"). Now all works as I wanted to)